# Drop bar to flat bar conversion

Tags: shifter, conversion, flatbar

Gearing             14-Speed Shimano A070 STI
Crankset            Prowheel Ounce 42/52T Double Chainring Alloy Crankset
Shifters            Shimano A070 STI
Front Derailleur    Shimano Claris
Rear Derailleur     Shimano A070
Brakes              Tektro Dual-Pivot Caliper Brakes
Brake Levers        Shimano A070 STI

Above is what I currently have. I am looking to convert from drop bar to flat bar to use the bike as a casual fitness and commuter bike. All I know is that some parts are road bike specific and may need replacing if I want the conversion done. I hear that the front derailleur, shifters/brake levers (obviously since it currently has STI) and the bar it self. Is there anything else that needs to be changed? I would like someone who has more knowledge in bikes than me to possibly tell me what parts from the above mentioned list needs to be changed. I am not looking to do any upgrades. Just looking for cheap budget parts since it will just be a leisure bike.

Thank you all

Sincerely

Tom.

Comment: This is generally not worth doing. unless you have a donor bike.  And if you have a donor, then its often easier to fix that and suddenly you have two working and rideable bikes.

Comment: Generally you will need a new stem.

Comment: Surely this kind of thing has been asked before, but all the questions I found were about converting in the opposite direction. Although essentially the same difficulties apply, I don't think they're really duplicates.

Comment: All I know is a bike manufacturer says it can be done.I wanted this done for my wife's bike. I did not ask for details.

Answer (score 4):

It's almost certainly going to be more cost effective to replace the whole bike, and selling the current one.

There are potential problems with both brake caliper and derailleur compatibility going to flat bar shifters.

Aside from replacing shifters, drivetrain and bar, drop bar road bikes have shorter frames than flat bar bikes, because the rider's hands are placed forward of the stem head on the drops or hoods, but a flat bar places them approximately level with stem head. You may find the seat to bar distance is too short with flat bar installed.

Comment: Thank you all. I will just keep it as is and get a new bike down the line.